# git cherry-pick - option to fail if resulting diff is different?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-cherry-pick

I have a situation where I'd like `git cherry-pick` to not "quietly return 0 when some of the source commit's diffs are already present in the destination". Yes, it fails if the resulting commit is empty, but I don't see the option to fail if the resulting commit is not-empty-but-not-the-same-diff-as-the-original. I do not see an option to `cherry-pick` to do this, and a quick look at `git merge` which I assume provides the underlying functionality for it, also doesn't *seem* to provide this, though I'm less sure. Is this possible?

---

Extra notes: yes, I can perform a diff between `git show <sourcecommit>` and `git show <destcommit>`. I do do that, in fact. But this can give a false failure if the cherry-pick picked up a change in a renamed file. I'd alternately be interested in a solution to this problem.

Comment: There is no built in way to do this. There probably should be, but it needs careful thought about interactions with `git rerere`.

Comment: Thanks. Interestingly, a diff of the `git show` *may* work, if you ignore filenames, but only if the renamed file still sorts alphabetically in the same order wrt the other files.

Comment: (I think I deserve special SO points for asking a git question that even @torek has no answer for. :-)